# Statement update with inner join on Oracle Error

Tags: oracle

I have a query which works fine in Sybase, but when I run it on Oracle I get the following error

```
update table1
        set chk = b.chkakhir
    from table1 a
    inner join (select substr('0'||inkdwil,-2) wil,substr(chk,-4) site, wil||site chkakhir,wil||'0' chkdcust from table2) b
        on a.chk = b.site   
    where length(a.chk) = 4;

update table1
        set chk = b.chkakhir
    from table1 a
    inner join (select right('0'||inkdwil,2) wil,right(chk,4) site, wil||site chkakhir,wil||'0' chkdcust from table2) b
        on a.chk = b.site   
    where len(a.chk) = 4;
```

query work in oracle

Comment: Can you please add the error (add it in a quote block to be readable) ?

Comment: Most likely *ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended*, due to the stray `from` following the `set` clause. ([Documentation for `UPDATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/UPDATE.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

query work in oracle

update table1
        set chk = (select chk
    from table1 a
    inner join (select substr('0'||inkdwil,-2) wil,substr(chk,-4) site, substr('0'||inkdwil,-2)||substr(chk,-4) chkakhir,substr('0'||inkdwil,-2)||'0' chkdcust from table2) b
        on a.chk = b.site)
    where length(a.chk) = 4;

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax, as far as Oracle is concerned. Should look like this:

```
UPDATE table1
   SET chk      =
          (SELECT b.chkakhir               --> instead of FROM, you have to use SELECT here
             FROM table1 a
                  INNER JOIN (SELECT SUBSTR ('0' || inkdwil, -2) wil,
                                     SUBSTR (chk, -4) site,
                                     wil || site chkakhir,
                                     wil || '0' chkdcust
                                FROM table2) b
                     ON a.chk = b.site
            WHERE LENGTH (a.chk) = 4);
```

Comment: Looks like a recipe for an ORA-1427 error if `table1` has more than one row in it.  Why include `table1` in the subquery rather than correlating it to the `table1` that you are updating?